# Context Project Seems to Ignore Products

Tags: context

When I typeset the following project, it seems that the products aren't being found. I can typeset the product itself without any trouble, but typsetting the project as a whole doesn't generate a PDF because , I assume, it can't find the products.

```
% Sam.tex
\environment Style
\startproject Sam
    \product Introduction
\stopproject

% Introduction.tex
\environment Style
\project Sam
\startproduct Introduction
    \component Section1
\stopproduct

% Section1.tex
\environment Style
\project Sam
\product Introduction
\startcomponent Section1
    Some content...
\stopcomponent
```

All files are, for simplicity, in the same directory. I have tried other directory structures, making the appropriate changes in the environment file.

I recently updated my context version and now none of my projects typeset.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A project cannot be typeset, only products and components. The mechanism was recently changed from a tolerant to a more strict version that now causes your problem.

Comment: So what purpose do projects serve if you can't typeset them? Incidentally, it does typeset. It just doesn't resolve the products.

Comment: To quote a mail of Hans: “Projects 
are just there to help clever editors to identify products.”

Comment: See also: http://pragma-ade.com/general/magazines/mag-1101.pdf